# Full Page Cache Infinite Redirect

Tags: product, catalog, redirect, full-page-cache

Full-page cache is turned on (Magento EE ver 1.14.0.1). However, some products are having redirect loop upon hitting the URL. No error in the logs. If I clear the `full_page_cache`, then it would now work. I searched for the `full_page_cache` folder for the problematic URLs  and here's what I got (in a serialized form):

```
array (
  'cache_subprocessor' => 'Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor_Product',
  'current_product_id' => '400',
  'response_headers' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Content-Type',
      'value' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      'replace' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'X-Frame-Options',
      'value' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'replace' => true,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'P3p',
      'value' => 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"',
      'replace' => true,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Location',
      'value' => 'http://www.example.com/this-is-the-product-url',
      'replace' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'routing_aliases' => 
  array (
    'rewrite_request_path' => 'this-is-the-product-url',
  ),
  'routing_requested_route' => 'catalog',
  'routing_requested_controller' => 'product',
  'routing_requested_action' => 'view',
  'sid_cookie_name' => 'frontend',
)
```

Other products don't have this:

```
   3 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Location',
      'value' => 'http://www.example.com/this-is-the-product-url',
      'replace' => true,
    ),
```

If I clear the full page cache, it would not occur, thus, intermittent to random products. I couldn't replicate what the cause of redirect loop is. Any idea?

Comment: I am also facing this same issue and didn't found any solution till now.

Comment: @AnshuMishra, do you use other caching mechanism, ie., cloudlflare?

Comment: Other than default Magento caching mechanism I am using Google Page Speed

Answer (score 3):

If you are using stock magento (no 3rd party modules) and experience this then the caching mechanisms defined may be the cause.  What are you using currently for block caching in `local.xml` and FPC caching in `enterprise.xml`?

Also here are some other related documents that may help understand FPC better, remember the block cache helps drive FPC:

[image]

- http://www.developers-paradise.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/NRG_-MDP_Presentation_Max_Gubar_Ibiza_2012.pdf
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn?rq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance/9225634#9225634

Comment: From enterprise.xml, here: <cache>
            <request_processors>
                <ee>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor</ee>
            </request_processors>
            <frontend_options>
                <slab_size>1040000</slab_size>
            </frontend_options>
        </cache>
        <full_page_cache>
            <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_File</backend>
            <backend_options>
                <cache_dir>full_page_cache</cache_dir>
            </backend_options>
        </full_page_cache>